# Attachment with Postal MVC don't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, email, attachment

I have a `MVC3 project`. In my contact page I would like to add the possibility of adding an attachment to Email sent by customer.

I am using `Postal`. It works well but I can't get the attachment working.

Here is the part of my code dealing with this:

I have a `model class`:

```
public class ContactEmail
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required!")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Address is required!")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [DisplayName("Email Address")]
    [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Email Address is not valid.")]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required!")]
    [DisplayName("Country")]
    public string country { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Subject")]
    public string subject { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Message is required!")]
    [DisplayName("Message")]
    [StringLength(1500)]
    public string message { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime datetime { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase attachment { get; set; }
```

Here is my `Postal Controller`:

```
public class PostalController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Send(ContactEmail model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            var ticket = random.Next(1000000000, 2000000000);

            dynamic courriel = new Email("Postal");
            courriel.To = "support@coderfortraders.com";
            courriel.Name = model.name;
            courriel.Country = model.country;
            courriel.Subject = model.subject;
            courriel.From = model.email;
            courriel.Message = model.message;
            courriel.TicketId = ticket;
            courriel.Attachment = model.attachment;
            //if (model.Attachment != null && model.Attachment.ContentLength > 0)
            //{
            //    var attachment = new Attachment(model.Attachment.InputStream, model.Attachment.FileName);
            //    courriel.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            //}
            //courriel.Attachment = model.Attachment; 

            courriel.Attach(new Attachment(model.attachment.InputStream, model.attachment.FileName));

            Task task = courriel.SendAsync();

            //courriel.Send();

            return RedirectToAction("Sent", "Contact");
        }

        ViewData["MessageSent"] = false;

        return View("~/Views/Contact/Contact.cshtml");
    }
```

and finally here is the form I use in my `Contact.cshtml view`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Send", "Postal"))
{        
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

    <p>
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name)
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.name, new { @size = 35 })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name, "*")
    </p>                      
    <p>
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email)
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.email, new { @size = 35 })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email, "*")
    </p>
    <p>
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.subject)
       @Html.DropDownList(
           "subject", 
           new[] { 
               new SelectListItem { 
                   Text = "NT Indicator Quote", 
                   Value = "NT Indicator Quote" 
               }, 
               new SelectListItem { 
                   Text = "NT Strategy Quote", 
                   Value = "NT Strategy Quote" 
               }, 
               new SelectListItem { 
                   Text = "Comments", 
                   Value = "Comments" 
               }, 
               new SelectListItem { 
                   Text = "other", 
                   Value = "other" 
               }
           }
       ); // @Html.DropDownList(
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.subject, "*")
    </p>
    <p>
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.message)
       @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.message, new { @cols = 50, @rows = 10 })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.message, "*")
    </p>
    <p>
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.attachment)
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.attachment, new { type = "file" })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.attachment)
    </p>          
    <p><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>            
} <!-- End form -->
```

I get the following error message :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>   Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Source Error: 
>   Line 44: courriel.Attach(new Attachment(model.attachment.InputStream, model.attachment.FileName));

Could you please help me find out the problem here ?
Thank you !

Here is the HTML from the view source :

```
<form action="/Postal/Send?enctype=multipart%2Fform-data" method="post">
    <div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true">
        <ul>
            <li style="display:none"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <p>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Name is required!" id="name" name="name" size="35" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="name" data-valmsg-replace="false">*</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Email Address is not valid." data-val-regex-pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}" data-val-required="Email Address is required!" id="email" name="email" size="35" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="email" data-valmsg-replace="false">*</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <select id="subject" name="subject">
            <option value="NT Indicator Quote">NT Indicator Quote</option>
            <option value="NT Strategy Quote">NT Strategy Quote</option>
            <option value="Comments">Comments</option>
            <option value="other">other</option>
        </select>
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="subject" data-valmsg-replace="false">*</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea cols="50" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Message must be a string with a maximum length of 1500." data-val-length-max="1500" data-val-required="Message is required!" id="message" name="message" rows="10">
        </textarea>
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="message" data-valmsg-replace="false">*</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="attachment">attachment</label>
        <input id="attachment" name="attachment" type="file" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="attachment" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form> <!-- End form -->

    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to append the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to the form if you want to upload files:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Send", "Postal", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
{
    ...
}
```

Also checkout this [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) by the Haacked.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work even if I add  new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" } to the form

Comment: @user508945, how does the generated HTML of the `<form>` tag look like when you browse the source of the web page?

Comment: Thnak you very much Darin. I added the FormMethod.Post and it magically worked.